# Color scale ignored by ggplot2 geom_point

Tags: r

```
  ggplot() +
       geom_point(data=as.data.frame(res), aes_string(x=res$log2FoldChange, y=-log10(res$padj)), colour="darkgrey", alpha=6/10, size=2) +
       geom_point(data=sig_data, aes_string(x=sig_data$log2FoldChange, y=-log10(sig_data$padj)), shape = 21, colour=sig_data$baseMean, alpha=5/10, fill = NA, size=2,stroke=0.75)+
       scale_color_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

No matter what I specify as a color scale, a silly rainbow scale is used without any legend indicating what the colors mean.

Comment: For colours to be properly mapped to a scale you need to include them inside the `aes()` or `aes_string()` call. I'm a bit confused by your plotting code as generally should you just use single strings corresponding to column names in `aes_string() ` calls.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that your syntax is wrong. It should be either

```
aes(x = log2FoldChange, y = -log10(padj), color = baseMean)
```

or if you're hellbent on using `aes_string`

```
aes_string(x = "log2FoldChange", y = "-log10(padj)", color = "baseMean"))
```

Here's an example

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = -log10(wt), color = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()

ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = "-log10(wt)", color = "as.factor(cyl)")) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: aes vs. aes_string does not appear to make a difference here. I tried adding as.factor to my color coding variable and ggplot still produces a rainbow coloring scale, ignoring the specified scale.

Comment: @James notice where I specify the `color` argument. It's inside the `aes()`. This is very important, because you want some variable _mapped_ to a color. I'll edit my answer.